# Scala (single) case classes instead of classes

Tags: scala, oop, functional-programming, case-class

I have a few simple classes containing some fields and no logic. Is it a good idea to implement them as case classes instead of classes?

I mean, what are downsides of

```
case class Point(x: Int, y: Int)
```

compared to

```
class Point(xc: Int, yc: Int) {
  val x: Int = xc
  val y: Int = yc
}
```

if I want `Point` to be an immutable data container with no methods?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is exactly what case classes are designed for. The downsides are negligible*, and several upsides (automatic `equals`, `hashCode`, `toString`, `copy`, `apply`, `unapply`, Product methods, etc.).

As an aside, Your class example can be simplified to `class Point(val x: Int, val y: Int)`

See also: [How does a case class differ from a normal class?](http://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/258)

- downsides: increased memory usage for the extra functions.

Comment: It needs to be `class Point(val x: Int, val y: Int)`. Only the `val` makes the fields public.

Comment: @Downvoter: Any feedback on how this could be improved?

Comment: Benefits almost never come without drawbacks. In this case, increased class size for methods that you may never use. Typically, of course, these increases are negligible.

Answer (score 4):

Downsides to using a case class? Marginal overhead at most, so basically none.

Defining `case class Point(x : Int, y : Int)`, however gives you `apply`, `unapply`, `copy`, `toString`, `hashCode`, and "getter" methods all within one line. `class Point` as defined above does not.

Comment: The `class Point` example actually does give getters.

Comment: Not automatically. They were explicitly defined in the OP's example, whereas in a case class they don't need to be.

Comment: Indeed, not automatically, but in the given example it is the case. A getter is defined automatically for class members that are public. Scala language specification §5.3: "If a formal parameter declaration _x : T_ is preceded by a `val` or `var` keyword, an accessor (getter) definition (§4.2) for this parameter is implicitly added to the class. The getter introduces a value member _x_ of class _c_ that is defined as an alias of the parameter."